# Looking for help in building a youtube video slider in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, youtube

I'm currently learning asp.net to learn how to make web applications. I have a goal of creating a youtube type video slider for my website, so I can display videos. I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction on how I would do this. I do not want to use any third part plugins and just allows me to drag and drop into stuff. I'm looking to code this from scratch using asp.net, javascript, jquery etc.

I was thinking a starting point might be creating a vertical table with embedded videos in them. Then have a slider control attached to that table using numerical values, so I can slide the video next-previous based on those numerical values from a button control. Maybe using ajax slider control? If anyone can point me in the right way to accomplish this it will be really helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want but if you want to embed videos in asp.net web page that can be done using an iframe check it out at [ASP.NET website](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/10-working-with-video)

Comment: Thank you. Ill check it out.